# How to inform foreign office in Germany regarding Blue card when leaving Germany?

Tags: germany

I am working in Germany since February, 2016 and I have a blue card which is valid till 2020. Due to some reasons am resigning my current job and leaving Germany permanently and moving back to my home country (non EU country). I know I have to inform foreign office if I switch jobs within first two years of getting a blue card. But there are no clear rules about what to do with the blue card while leaving Germany? I checked the foreign office website and there are no details regarding this.